# How do I sort by unique attributes while counting with the Rails find statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've created a site where I can sell music in Rails. I'm wanting to return the most popular artists of the week based on sales of their music. Below is a brief overview of the models relations.

## Models

```
# Artist
attr_accessible :name, :website etc.

has_many :songs, :through => :artist_song
has_many :artist_song

# Cart

attr_accessible :purchased_at, :user_id, :id, :songs, :cart_song
      
has_many :songs, :through => :cart_song
has_many :cart_song

# Song

has_many :carts, :through => :cart_song
has_many :cart_song
      
has_many :artists, :through => :artist_song
has_many :artist_song
```

I can retrieve all sold songs for the last 'x' days with the code below but am unsure how to implement the grouping or counting within these results.

```
Song.find(:all, :conditions => ['carts.purchased_at IS NOT NULL AND carts.purchased_at >= ?', 7.days.ago.at_midnight], :include => :carts)
```

I'm guessing you would do some form of grouping or counting by a unique attribute, but I'm kind of stuck from here so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Song.select('?').where(
  'carts.purchased_at IS NOT NULL AND carts.purchased_at >= ?',
  7.days.ago.at_midnight
  ).includes(:carts).group('?')
```

Where ? is some attribute you want to group on.  You'll end up with one record returned for each group.